# Open new url with javascript and submit a form on the new site

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to make a script that opens a new window and in that window there is a form to call. I want to just to call the form from the new window and return back.

My code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function launchproducts (form) {

var input_from_user = form.inputbox.value;

for ( var i = 0; i < input_from_user ; i++) {
   var launch_code = "http://example.com";  
   window.open(launch_code, '_blank');       
   document.forms[2].submit();
    }
   }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">Enter product numbers: <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE=""><P>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="launchproducts(this.form)">
</FORM>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Look at your JavaScript console. What does it say?

Comment: (Why are you writing HTML 3.2 in this century?)

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? "call the form" doesn't make sense, do you mean submit?. What do you want to "return back"?

Comment: The code is from an old example that's why is old html. I have to submit an external form in a site(example.com). When i submit that button it generates an excel file. I want that file. When i am in console in that site and i hit document.forms[2].submit(); i get the excel file

Comment: you can't execute js on a page from another domain, https://www.google.com.au/search?q=same+origin+policy